# Is there any way to get the k smallest elements from a list without sorting it in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, time-complexity

I want to retrieve k smallest elements from a list in python. But I want to achieve this with less than *O(n log n)*(that is, without sorting the list) complexity. Is there any way to do so in Python. If yes please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I think [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) is what you are looking for.

> Quickselect uses the same overall approach as quicksort, choosing one element as a pivot and partitioning the data in two based on the pivot, accordingly as less than or greater than the pivot. However, instead of recursing into both sides, as in quicksort, quickselect only recurses into one side – the side with the element it is searching for. This reduces the average complexity from O(n log n) to O(n), with a worst case of O(n2).
>
> -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped me in my work and I got to learn new algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a few ways sorting/non-sorting solution for this problem:

1. Rank Selection Algorithm - like quicksort, we can find pivot rank then decide on whether to go left or right, O(N) time
2. Build a Min Heap O(N), extract k times - O(N + kLogN) time
3. Priority Queue - like max heap (remove biggest element if there is a new smaller), but instead we can loop through the entire array, build a heap of k size - O(N + NlogK)
4. Bubble Sort - bubble smallest few element upwards - O(k*N)

Comment: Thank you very much. You have broadened the my thinking space for finding the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the heapq.nsmallest, it performs with partial heap-sort

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.